# Sinon spy does not get called

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

The test is failing on the first expectation. Is there a way to inject a spy to a function so that I can check if the function was called with correct arguments?

```
            var myObj = {}
            myObj.prop = function propFn () {
                return 'foo'
            }

            myObj.func = function (disp) {
                return disp(this.prop())
            }

            let disp = sinon.spy()
            sinon.stub(myObj, 'prop').callsFake(function fakeFn () {
                return 'bar'
            })

            expect(disp.called).to.be.true
            disp.should.have.been.calledWith('bar')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below,

```
describe('prop', () => {
  const myObj = {};
  myObj.prop = function propFn() {
    return 'foo';
  };

  myObj.func = function (disp) {
    return disp(this.prop());
  };
  it('should be called', () => {
    sinon.stub(myObj, 'prop').returns('bar');
    const disp = sinon.spy();
    myObj.func(disp);
    expect(disp.callCount).to.equal(1);
    expect(myObj.prop.callCount).to.equal(1);
    expect(disp.callCount).to.equal(1);
    expect(disp.calledWith('bar')).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

result

> prop
>
> ✓ should be called
>
> 1 passing (975ms)